# Conditions for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with following problem so please help me out!

> Let's assume A and B are subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. Find the necessary and sufficient conditions for there to be a continuous function $f$  on $\mathbb R^n$ with $f|_A = 1$ and  $f|_B = 0$.

Please help me how to approach the problem. Hints and helps are greatly appreciated!

Comment: First: Your question is a little unclear --- where is it from? Perhaps you can post a more complete version. Are you trying to show that you can separate $A$ and $B$ with a continuous function?  Second: If $\, A \cup B= \mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ will never be continuous. You can picture, for example, $A=(-\infty,0]$ and $B=(0,\infty)$ for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but how do i start off to make $f$ to be continuous on $\mathbb R^n $ to be continuous. Thanks tho!

Comment: What I'm saying is that there may be no continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies $f|_A=0$ and $f|_B=1$ unless you put additional conditions on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I edited the the question.

Comment: Isn't it $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$ (where $\bar C$ is the closure of $C$)?

Comment: You are right the intersection of A and B has to be empty set given constraints.

Comment: don't forget closure: if $f=1$ on $A$ then $f=1$ on $\overline A$ too, by continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition, as pointed out by Surb, is that $\overline A \cap \overline B = \emptyset$.

Proof. If $f|_A = 1$ and $f|_B = 0$, then by continuity $f|_{\overline A} = 1$ and $f|_{\overline B} = 0$, hence $\overline A \cap \overline B = \emptyset$.

For the other direction, use that the distance function $d$ is continuous (in any metric space, and in particular in $\mathbb R^n$). Also, for any $x$, $d(x,A):=\inf\{d(x,a):a\in A\}=0$ if and only if $x \in \overline A$. Define $$f(x)=\frac{d(x,B)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$$ 
If $\overline A \cap \overline B = \emptyset$ then at least one of the summands in the denominator is positive, hence $f$ is well-defined and continuous. If $x\in \overline B$ then $d(x,B)=0$, hence $f(x)=0$. If $x\in \overline A$ then $d(x,A)=0$ and $d(x,B)>0$, hence $f(x)=\frac{d(x,B)}{0+d(x,B)}=1$.

Comment: Thanks! That helps me understand the problem a lot. But I am curious why do you define $f(x)$ as $f(x) = d(x,B) \ over {d(x,A)+d(x,B)} $. Thanks again!

Comment: because that is how it was defined years ago when I studied topology, in the book, and because this is the way it works, check it.

Comment: where do i check? Any links? Topology was covered just a bit in my real analysis class. Thanks though!

Comment: Well, the whole solution is written above, if you follow it why do you need other links: It answers your question completely. Any topology book should work, e.g Willard, General topology has the above as an exercise 15C on p.105. There is also a [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Topology) though perhaps a traditional paper book is better.

Comment: Thanks! I am asking links to read more about topology, not for answer. Sorry for confusing. I believed that it was a right answer. Thanks again!

Comment: glad you are interested